# How to increase cassandra disk I/O

Tags: io, cassandra

I have 3 node in Cassandra cluster on AWS platform. I have noticed that on any job/task performed by spark the I/O rate of cassandra (measured by collectd to graphite to grafana) is very low- the max number of Disk Read Operations/Sec and  Disk Write Operations/Sec is 75.

It seems like a throttling problem...So how can I increase cassandra disk I/O rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential environmental issues aside, if you are using the spark-cassandra-connector you can tune the write throughput settings to see if you can achieve higher disk I/O.  You can tune batch size, batch level (i.e. by partition or by replica set), write throughput in mb per core, concurrent batches per spark task, among other things using [`WriteConf`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/d8585830330ce7bd6ccd3cd09fb7812c7e166d8d/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/writer/WriteConf.scala#L57-L113).

When calling `saveToCassandra`, `saveAsCassandraTable`, etc. you can pass writeConf as a parameter, i.e.:

```
rdd.saveToCassandra(keyspace, table, writeConf=WriteConf(...))
```

otherwise you can configure via your SparkConf by setting the properties defined in WriteConf.  For example, configuring `spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes` will override the default number of concurrent writes per task.

Comment: I think my problem is "Potential environmental issues aside". Maybe configuration changes like cassandra.yaml is the problem?

Comment: Is there anything else that indicates that writes aren't being serviced?  It is either that the client is not producing enough write requests, or the server isn't able to service them quickly enough.  It may be good to look at the nodetool cfhistograms (http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCFhisto.html) and proxyhistograms (http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsProxyHistograms.html) stats to see if writes are being serviced at a reasonable rate and are being serviced quickly.

Comment: Another thing I should note is that the write path doesn't touch the disk until it flushes sstables.  So even though many writes may be in flight, cassandra doesn't actually go to disk until it reaches some threshold/conditon where writes in memory (memtables) are flushed to disk (sstables): https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html